# Setting up Django with Eclipse - "Django not found"

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev, django-errors

I'm trying to setup Django with Eclipse. Right now I'm creating a new Pydev Django project, and getting "Django not found" error message.

When I try to verify Django is integrated via the command line, it works.

```
>>> import django
>>> print django.get_version()
1.2.5
```

I have exactly two python installations, 2.7 and 3.2, and I'm sure I'm using 2.7 from Eclipse (and the command line). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you added interpreters? Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter *;

Comment: @JackLeo - Yes I have, I added the correct interpreters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you added the python interpreter before installing django, you can get this error message. Remove the python interpreter from eclipse and add it again. Eclipse will do some caching/searching of some sort. This solved my same problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, have spent a few hours looking at various solutions. At first the above did not work but once I restarted Eclipse it worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case I use virtualenv and a custom local version of easy_install to avoid needing to be root. I have Django installed in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. I added this path in Eclipse in the PyDev interpreter.

However, this did not fix the problem. It turned out that I needed to explicitly add the Django directory as well (ie: `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/`).

So remember to explicitly select the Django directory in PyDev interpreter especially if you have stuff customized in some fashion.